# Why might have my website dropped off SERPS?

Tags: seo

I used to be first page for a keyword, but now it seems I have dropped off entirely and cannot even find myself on the first few pages. I checked Google webmaster tools and there wasn't anything peculiar. I'm guessing I need to build new backlinks, but any other ideas?

Comment: Did you check if you dropped some (or many) positions, or if your sites it's de-indexed? (search "site:www.example.co.uk")

Answer (score 2):

I posted these links in another answer:

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/recovery-from-google-penguin-tips-from-the-trenches

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/penguins-pandas-and-panic-at-the-zoo

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-wpmuorg-recovered-from-the-penguin-update

You may have been hit by a change of the Google algorithm. If you find pages at all in the SERP it's at least no mistake by accident in the robots.txt or something like that. As you don't write enough details about your project (do you have high quality content? some site-authority? some content of age? quality backlinks by sites not hit by recent Google updates?

Just read the articles above and see if you find yourself in the boat.